# Converting Tableau cF (Calculated Fields) into Power Query/DAX Microsoft

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am working on a IIF statement in Tableau which I am hoping to convert to Power Query/Microsoft. I am not sure entirely if this will be in DAX or Power Query. Converting Tableau workbooks to PowerBI.
I regularly check online to see if there are any examples on IIF statements but they mostly pointed to IF statements and not IIF. Kindly requesting help on converting this Tableau calculated field example into Microsoft Power Query or DAX. Here is the Tableau (CF) example:

```
IF {FIXED [ticketnumber]: SUM(IIF([SLAstatus]="Met",1,0)) +
SUM(IIF([SLAstatus]="Missed",1,0))} > 0 THEN "SLA" ELSE "No SLA" END
```

Here is what I have tried (I am removing the FIXED part for now)

```
= CALCULATE(SUM([SLAstatus]),"Met" AND (SUM([SLAstatus]),"Missed" > 0,"SLA","No SLA"
```